# Kotlin code not working as intended after first time

Tags: android, kotlin

I coded a basic android app using Kotlin in which when I click the button it shows pop up to allow user to give the "READ_PHONE_STATE" permission to the app which results in a Toast (permission granted) or a Toast (permission already granted) if it is already granted . It worked fine in first run but after that even if I delete the app or clear the data of the app from the android simulator it does not start from the beginning like when I click on the  button it either state "permission already granted" or "permission not granted " based on state of the "phone permission" in the android setting (simulator).

Help is its something because of how I wrote the code or it is something default to the android studio etc?

```
package com.example.androidproject

import android.Manifest
import android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
       val btnRequest = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnRequest)
        btnRequest.setOnClickListener{
            if(checkPermission()){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Already Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()


            }
            else{
                // request for permissions

                val permissionToRequest = listOf("READ_PHONE_STATE")
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissionToRequest.toTypedArray(), 0 )
            }
        }

    }

    //check permission
    private fun checkPermission(): Boolean{
    return     ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

// result of requested permissions
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    if(requestCode == 0 && grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        Toast.makeText(this, "The permission has been granted of ${permissions[0]}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission not granted ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: IIRC, permission status is not considered part of the app’s data that you can clear. I would expect it to reset after uninstalling it, though.

Comment: Permission didn't reset after uninstalling the app. ;(